# SQL Null set to Zero for adding

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I have a SQL query (MS Access) and I need to add two columns, either of which may be null. For instance:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3+Column4 AS [Added Values]
FROM Table
```

where Column3 or Column4 may be null. In this case, I want null to be considered zero (so `4 + null = 4, null + null = 0`).

Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since ISNULL in Access is a boolean function (one parameter), use it like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, IIF(ISNULL(Column3),0,Column3) + IIF(ISNULL(Column4),0,Column4) AS [Added Values]
FROM Table
```

Comment: In access, though, ISNULL is just a boolean function, not a conditional (so it only takes one parameter, and returns whether it's null). Is there a way of doing conditional things in Access?
(http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php)

Comment: Yeah, I just found the IIF statement, and it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: Personally if you're going to be calling this query a lot then I'd create a view with null replacement already applied.  It'll make your code considerably cleaner and apart from striving for elegance clean code is generally less likely to cause maintenance errors later.

Comment: Using `expr IS NULL`is better than `ISNULL(expr)`. See the link on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461079/78522

Answer (score 4):

According to [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html), the fastest way is to use `IIF(Column3 is Null; 0; Column3)` because both `NZ()` and `ISNULL()` are VBA functions and calling VBA functions slows down the JET queries.

I would also add that if you work with linked SQL Server or Oracle tables, the IIF syntax also the query to be executed on the server, which is not the case if you use VBA functions.

Answer (score 2):

Even cleaner would be the nz function

```
nz (column3, 0)
```

Comment: Note that if you use Nz(), the Nz command is not present in the vba language directly.  Normally this has no impact, but if you use linked query in Excel from Access, Nz won't work.  But you can still use the iif( isnull()... )  construct.

Comment: @Knox: you are right on the effect, but wrong on the cause I think: NZ is VBA and not SQL, that's why it fails when called from external apps. I have also seen that it is slower then IIF construct for the same reason: calling VBA.

Comment: We agree that Nz is not SQL.  However, since Excel runs full blown VBA and can talk to databases either with or without Access, and since excel can in no circumstances use Nz() we can conclude that Nz is a function specific to Access.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ISNULL** replacement command:

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2, ISNULL(Column3, 0) + ISNULL(Column4, 0) AS [Added Values]FROM Table
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Access/Jet/ACE. The equivalent to that IsNull() is Nz(), but it's not available in all contexts outside of Access itself, so you have to use IIf() logic with the Access/Jet/ACE IsNull() function (which simply returns true or false based on whether the passed express is Null or not), which is always available.

Comment: This is not for Access as specified in OP's product definition.

Answer (score 1):

The Nz() function from VBA can be used in your MS Access query.

This function substitute a NULL for the value in the given parameter.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Nz(Column3, 0) + Nz(Column4, 0) AS [Added Values]
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

In your table definition, set the default for Column3 and Column4 to zero, therefore when a record is added with no value in those columns the column value will be zero.  You would therefore never have to worry about null values in queries.

Answer (score -1):

Use COALESCE.

```
SELECT 
   Column1, 
   Column2, 
   COALESCE(Column3, 0) + COALESCE(Column4, 0) AS [Added Values]
FROM Table
```

Comment: No COALESCE in Access: there is NZ() but it is slightly different.

Comment: This is not for Access as specified in OP's product definition.