# how can I replace blank value with zero in MS-Acess

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have below query in Ms-Access but I want to replace Blank value with zero but I can't get proper answer. Is there any way to replace blank value in zero.

```
(SELECT 
   SUM(IIF(Review.TotalPrincipalPayments,0,Review.TotalPrincipalPayments))+
   SUM(IIF(Review.TotalInterestPayments,0,Review.TotalInterestPayments ))
 FROM 
   tblReviewScalars as Review 
 INNER JOIN tblReportVectors AS Report ON(Review.LoanID=Report.LoanID) 
 WHERE Report.AP_Indicator="A" AND Report.CashFlowDate=#6/5/2011# AND Review.AsofDate=#6/5/2011# AND ( Review.CreditRating =ReviewMain.CreditRating)) AS [Cash Collected During the Period],
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `TotalPrincipalPayments` and `TotalInterestPayments` are both numeric types, hence the 'blanks' in question is the `NULL` value.

In SQL, the set function `SUM` will disregard NULL values, unless all values resolve to `NULL` in which case `NULL` is returned (erroneously and the error is with SQL not Access for a change :)

To use a simple example, `SELECT SUM(a) FROM T;` will only return `NULL` when `a IS NULL` is TRUE for all rows of `T` or when `T` is empty. Therefore, you can move the 'replace `NULL` with zero' logic outside of the `SUM()` function. Noting that "`NULL`s propagate" in calculations, you will need to handle `NULL` for each `SUM()`.

You haven't posted the whole of your query e.g. the source of the correlation name ('table alias') `ReviewMain` is not showm. But it seems clear you are constructing a derived table named `"Cash Collected During the Period"`, in which case your calculated column needs an `AS` clause ('column alias') such as `TotalPayments` e.g.

```
...
(
 SELECT IIF(SUM(Review.TotalPrincipalPayments) IS NULL, 0, SUM(Review.TotalPrincipalPayments))
        +  IIF(SUM(Review.TotalInterestPayments) IS NULL, 0, SUM(Review.TotalInterestPayments))
           AS TotalPayments
   FROM tblReviewScalars as Review 
        INNER JOIN tblReportVectors AS Report 
           ON Review.LoanID = Report.LoanID 
  WHERE Report.AP_Indicator = 'A' 
        AND Report.CashFlowDate = #2011-05-06# 
        AND Review.AsofDate = #2011-05-06# 
        AND Review.CreditRating = ReviewMain.CreditRating
) AS [Cash Collected During the Period], ...
```

Comment: +1; totally agree. Anyway here is something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137398/sql-null-set-to-zero-for-adding/137410#137410. I'm gonna lose my 2k for now :'(

Comment: @daemon_x: if the choice is between `x IS NULL` and `ISNULL(x)` I'd choose the former because a) it is Standard SQL, b) it is IMO easier to read, c) SQL Server has an `ISNULL()` function that has different behaviour. I wish Access had a native `COALESCE()` function.

Comment: In a WHERE clause, `x Is Null` is superior because it will use the index, whereas `IsNull(x)` won't.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I believe you but... really?! It never ceases to amaze me how often the Access team fail to capitalize on low-hanging fruit. How difficult can it be for the parser to transform one to the other?

Comment: Well, the query optimizer would have to understand when one is really meaning to write something that is equivalent. I'd rather the query optimizer leave my SQL alone, except where there really is a 1:1 correspondence between the alternative interpretations. In this case, IsNull() can be used in a lot of circumstances where it would be inappropriate to convert it to the SQL alternative. And in a SELECT statement (e.g., `IIf(IsNull(...)...`), indexes don't matter, anyway, so no conversion would be necessary.

Comment: The attitude about "low hanging fruit" seems to leave the Access team in a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" position. They come under criticism all the time from PEOPLE LIKE YOU for implementing features they see as time-saving which you don't like. This is one where I wouldn't want the query optimizer to rewrite my SQL (though I have no problem with most of the rewriting it does do) -- I want it to do what I tell it to do, even if that's inefficient, because the alternative is much worse, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @onedaywhen's answer is to use the `nz` function, which is specifically for null-substitution:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(NZ(Review.TotalPrincipalPayments,0))+
   SUM(NZ(Review.TotalInterestPayments,0))
...
```

As onedaywhen pointed out, this is functionally equivalent to putting the function outside the aggregate, which may perform better (the function is called once, rather than once per un-aggregated row):

```
SELECT 
   NZ(SUM(Review.TotalPrincipalPayments),0)+
   NZ(SUM(Review.TotalInterestPayments),0)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a null value to a zero in an Access 2010 database, open your table, go to design view, click on the field and set the default value to: `=0`.